# Office365 Group, drive is inaccessible for long time

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Recently we have discovered that when Private Office 365 Group is created via Microsoft graph, its Drive is inaccessible for quite a longer time than before.
Before if we were creating such a group as an application, the drive would have been setup in less than a minute.

Now we have a situation where group drives are inaccessible for few hours. 
Has anything changed in the meantime?

You can test the behavior by creating the group on the graph explorer using following request:

```
{
  "description": "test",
  "displayName": "test",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "test",
  "securityEnabled": false,
  "visibility": "private"
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're seeing a several hour delay when creating a private group but not what creating a public group?

Comment: Yes, if group is public, drive is ready to be used within 1 minute.